# Gamerules in Minecraft "Unknown Command"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm a newbie to Minecraft, and not a computer whiz, so I fully expect I'm going something wrong here.

I've been trying to use the keepInventory cheat in Minecraft but it always says "Unknown Command" and no options come up when I put in /gamerules (all that comes up is /gamemode). I've been having a streak of getting killed with some awesome stuff in my inventory and I desperately want to keep this from happening again!

I have cheats enabled. Is there something I'm missing? How so I solve this?

Comment: press tab twice when typeing: /game <tab x2> . If it switches to /gamerule its not an issue of the game only your knowledge :)

Comment: Ok, to clarify, each space in the command is not a space but 2 tabs? So /gamerule *tab x 2* keepInventory *tab x2* true

Comment: No what I meant by <tab> is the shortcut for commands. So say you have:
/game < That is when you click tab without a space (The tab button) it should come up with:
/gamemode
And then if you click tab again:
it should be /gamerule
and then to finish:
/gamerule keepInventory true

Comment: Ok, gotcha. /gamerule does not come up as a possible command, only /gamemode

Comment: What version of minecraft are you runnong

Answer (score 3):

From [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Summary_of_commands):

```
/gamerule
```

Sets or queries a game rule value.

Syntax

```
Computer

gamerule <rule name> [value]

Pocket Edition

gamerule <rule: string> <value: bool>
gamerule <rule: string> <value: int>
gamerule [rule: string]
```

- 

Additionally, issuing `/gamerule` by itself will list available game rules.

The particular gamerule you are seeking is called keepInventory.

Issue the following command:

```
/gamerule keepInventory true
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to use `/gamerules` instead of the correct one `/gamerule`. It is without the s on the end.